# ui-sref fires before loading the dynamic states. How to stop this?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

Hi I am trying to load states dynamically through an ajax request in the app.run() method.
In the same page, I have a link with ui-sref pointing to this dynamic state.

While loading the page, the ui-sref fires before this load and says state not found.
Any trick how we can overcome this?

Comment: Please post your code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't retrieve the states in app.run. Only bootstrap your app after the ajax request is returned.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to both Javascript and angular. Are you saying to bootstrap the entire angular after the ajax? If yes, what is the right way to store the states on the client side - a Global variable or can i add the states to the config directly before bootstrap?

Comment: Storing the states as a global variable or in local storage is entirely up to you. you can even delete it after you have configured your routes. But I don't think you can configure states before bootstrap as config is a part of bootstraping.